# Facebook App with Standard Setting without Ad Management

Tags: facebook, facebook-apps

We have tried to create an App that will be able to access only Reporting and Insights for a user via Marketing Insights API. I have noticed that the requirement for Basic access is listed as:
"Apps should create sufficient ads that pass ad review and do not contain bad creatives"

But my App is NOT intended to create ads. It is a data reporting App and without standard access I have to add each user into Ads API under Advertising Accounts section of the App Settings. I would like to use this app across FB accounts of my clients to only pull data related to the ads. Could you please help me understand how to accomplish this without having to create a separate Dev app for each client?

Answer (score 0):

You could try to [apply directly](https://www.facebook.com/business/standardadsapi) for the *Standard Access* tier. In that form you can explain your use case and then it will be processed.

I would advise to already make various valid requests from your *Development Tier* to show you have a correct implementation.